# How many ships are ready to launch?

Tags: iss, spacecraft, rescue-missions

In the wake of the Russian launch failure to send more astronauts to the ISS, it got me thinking. How many "ready to fly" ships are there? And, if an accident were to happen and the current ISS crew needed to be rescued, how long would it take to respond?

How many in a month?
7 days or less?
Less than a day?

I'll take estimates!

What's the amount of government agencies and private companies that have or are working on a manned mission.

How many assembled launch systems are there?

How long would it take to assemble a whole launch system?

Comment: Welcome to *Space!*  This question does ask about the same scenario than the older question linked above.  You need to edit the question to make it unique.  I think the "ready to fly" (in ___ days) is distinct enough from the old question.  However, the agencies/companies and how long it would take is already covered by the older question.